# isnull() and dropna() not working for pandas 0.22 when using xlwings to get dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xlwings

Desperate about this mystery. So i just upgraded my pandas to 0.22 (from 0.18) and mysteriously, when using `xlwings`, `dropna` or `isnull` does NOT work anymore. I see that myTemp is still giving me the correct True and False, yet 
`unwindDF` will give me all the `df_raw` data just with everything filled to become nan and naT. Similar issue for noPx.

This is the case even if I manually assign `np.nan` to a cell  Yet surprisingly, when in the same file I create a simple df towards the end, then myTest1
is working well. why? is there something special about `xlwings` with pandas 0.22?

My code is below and my xlsx file in the image.

```
import pythoncom
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np


folder_path = 'S:/Order/all PNL files/'
excel_name='pnlTest.xlsx'
pnl_excel_path = folder_path + excel_name
sheetName = 'Sheet1'

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
app = None
bk = None
app_count = xw.apps.count
for i in range(app_count):
    try:
        app = xw.apps[i]
        temp = app.books[excel_name]
        bk = temp
        print()
        print("Using Opened File")
    except:
        print()
if bk == None:
    print("Open New Excel App")
    app = xw.App()
    bk = xw.Book(pnl_excel_path)

bk.app.calculation = 'manual'
bk.app.screen_updating = False

sht = bk.sheets[sheetName]
last_row_index = sht.range('A1').end('down').row
df_raw = sht.range('A1:M' + str(last_row_index)).options(pd.DataFrame, header=1,
index=0).value
myTemp = df_raw['UNWD_DT'].isnull()
unwindDF = df_raw[df_raw['UNWD_DT'].isnull()]
df_raw.loc[10,'Curr_Px']=np.nan
df_raw.iloc[10,11]=np.nan
noPx=df_raw[df_raw['Curr_Px'].isnull()]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1],'c':[np.nan,1,0,np.nan]})
myTemp1=df['c'].isnull()
myTest1=df[df['c'].isnull()]
df_raw.dropna(thresh=2,inplace=True)
df_raw2=df_raw.dropna(thresh=2)
```

[image: a]